# Count cycles of length 3 using DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Let `G=(V,E)` be an undirected graph. How can we count cycles of length 3 exactly once using following DFS:

```
DFS(G,s):
    foreach v in V do
        color[v] <- white; p[v] <- nil
    DFS-Visit(s)

DFS-Visit(u)
    color[u] <- grey
    foreach v in Adj[u] do
        if color[v] = white then 
            p[v] = u; DFS-Visit(v)
    color[u] <- black
```

There is a cycle whenever we discover a node that already has been discovered (grey). The edge to that node is called back edge. The cycle has length 3 when `p[p[p[v]]] = v`, right? So

```
DFS-Visit(u)
    color[u] <- grey
    foreach v in Adj[u] do
        if color[v] = grey and p[p[p[v]]] = v then
            // we got a cycle of length 3
        else if color[v] = white then 
            p[v] = u; DFS-Visit(v)
    color[u] <- black
```

However how can I create a proper counter to count the number of cycles and how can I count each cycle only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand how your condition `parent[parent[parent[v]]] == v` works. IMO it should never be true as long as `parent` represents a structure of tree (because it should correspond to the spanning tree associated with the DFS).

#### Directed graphs

Back edges, cross edges and forward edges can all "discover" new cycles. For example:

[image: Cycle with cross edge]

We separate the following possibilities (let's say you reach a `u -> v` edge):

- Back edge: `u` and `v` belongs to the same 3-cycle iff `parent[parent[u]] = v`.
- Cross edge: `u` and `v` belongs to the same 3-cycle iff `parent[u] = parent[v]`.
- Forward edge: `u` and `v` belongs to the same 3-cycle iff `parent[parent[v]] = u`.

#### Undirected graphs

There are no more cross edges. Back edges and forward edges are redundant. Therefore you only have to check back edges: when you reach a `u -> v` back edge, `u` and `v` belongs to the same 3-cycle iff `parent[parent[u]] = v`.

```
def dfs(u):
    color[u] = GREY
    for v in adj[u]:
        # Back edge
        if color[v] == GREY:
            if parent[parent[u]] == v: 
                print("({}, {}, {})".format(v + 1, parent[u] + 1, u + 1))
        # v unseen
        elif color[v] == WHITE:
            parent[v] = u
            dfs(v)
    color[u] = BLACK
```

If you want to test it:

```
WHITE, GREY, BLACK = 0, 1, 2
nb_nodes, nb_edges = map(int, input().split())
adj = [[] for _ in range(nb_nodes)]
for _ in range(nb_edges):
    u, v = map(int, input().split())
    adj[u - 1].append(v - 1) 
    adj[v - 1].append(u - 1) 
parent = [None] * nb_nodes
color = [WHITE] * nb_nodes
```

Comment: Sorry parent suggests a wrong meaning. I corrected it. p[v] is the previous visited node. So when we discover a back edge and check p[p[p[v]]] it should contain v when we have a 3 node cycle, right? You say consider cross/forward edges, however isn't it always a back edge that creates a cycle? Because a node has to be previously visited (grey) in order to create a cycle. Also could you put your idea into the given pseudo code to get complete view on your solution? Thanks ;)

Comment: @md5 in an undirected graph, like the one of the question, Back, Cross, and Forward Edge have no meaning

Comment: @zabware: I don't understand exactly what "previous visited node" means (what if the node is grey, etc.). I think it's easier to speak in terms of parent in the [DFS spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search) (which is well-defined). See my updated answer, cross and forward edges are in fact only interesting for directed graphs.

Comment: @Matt: I believe they actually have meaning, because the resulting spanning tree _is_ directed (or could be considered so). But you're right, these are not interesting with undirected graphs (and my example with cross edges cannot happen in such a case).

Comment: DFS for undirected graph does not work. Consider this example with 4 cycles of length = 3: https://gist.github.com/miguelmartin75/f01d86668ec565fd4638a3f2b550065f

Answer (score 0):

If a solution without using DFS is okay, there is an easy solution which runs in O(NMlog(N³)) where N is the number of vertices in the graph and M is the number of edges.

We are going to iterate over edges instead of iterating over vertices. For every edge u-v, we have to find every vertex which is connected to both u and v. We can do this by iterating over every vertex w in the graph and checking if there is an edge v-w and w-u. Whenever you find such vertex, order u,v,w and add the ordered triplet to a BBST that doesn't allow repetitions (eg: std::set in C++). The count of length 3 cycles will be exactly the size of the BBST (amount of elements added) after you check every edge in the graph.

Let's analyze the complexity of the algorithm:

1. We iterate over every edge. Current complexity is O(M)
2. For each edge, we iterave over every vertex. Current complexity is O(NM)
3. For each (edge,vertex) pair that forms a cycle, we are going to add a triplet to a BBST. Adding to a BBST has O(log(K)) complexity where K is the size of the BST. In worst case, every triplet of vertices forms a cycle, so we may add up to O(N³) elements to the BST, and the complexity to add some element can get as high as O(log(N³)). Final complexity is O(NMlog(N³)) then. This may sound like a lot, but in worst case M = O(N²) so the complexity will be O(N³log(N³)). Since we may have up to O(N³) cycles of length 3, our algorithm is just a log factor away from an optimal algorithm.